# UI Component(Table Rows) Taking Too Much too in LWC

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have a lwc component(Salesforce) where we are showing a table and approx 300 rows, the data from backend comes quickly at once.. I have added pagination,when doing next and previous , the rows are taking too much time to load, Now how do i even put spinner , since the data is already loaded and assignment of new set of rows also happens quickly, just Ui component take a lot of time

Pagination for 10,50 rows works fine, but lagging a bit for more than 50 rows and even more for 300 rows.